# At what age/size will an avocado tree survive a European winter?

Tags: avocado, overwintering

Me and my brown thumb finally managed to grow an avocado tree. I'd like to grow it for a while and then plant it in the garden in a few years. I read that avocados shouldn't be left outside during the winter but some sites state that older plants tend to be more robust. Wikipedia says these trees will grow to heights of 20 metres so I figured at some point, it should be able to survive a few days below zero. Is this assumption correct?

Comment: „European winter“ as in Sicily or Tromsø? The answer will depend upon local climate above all, so maybe rephrasing the question towards age-dependent temperature thresholds  would be a good idea?

Comment: That said, if you picked a supermarket avocado in Germany, you likely got a Hass avocado - the type with the thick skin, between dark green and almost black. They are very cold sensitive, go below -3 or -4 °C for a mature plant and they are done for. And well above that they will receive significant cold damage that will have them drop their leaves etc.

Comment: Check the bark colour - Avacado can only survive frost (and intense sun) after "maturity" when the bark turns brown. In nature this is when it grows up through the undergrowth into the weather.

Comment: If you post this as a response, I'll accept it.